# Dynamically add div: fixed, dynamic width, centred

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I know this is a common issue, but hear me out, because I haven't seen any solutions that have worked.

This centred div works perfectly on jsfiddle, but not with my chrome extension. In my chrome extension I dynamically append a div with this css to the body of a given webpage (using document.body.appendChild), but it doesn't show up. When I inspect further, I can see that the website that I am visiting is applying it's own styles to my div; I'm not sure if this affects things.

http://jsfiddle.net/StEek/

html:

```
.myDiv{
    position: fixed;
    /* center the element */
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    /* give it dimensions */
    min-height: 10em;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

css:

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <p>coolio</p>
</div>
```

Is there any way to dynamically add a div, with ONLY my style applied to it, to ANY webpage? I want a fixed, dynamic width centred div that will be appended to the body element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your div an `id` and set your styles for that `id` instead of the `class` element.

If a website set styles for all divs on the webpage, you will need to override these styles with your own.

Comment: Also, add `!important` to each style in your CSS file. You could also not use a `div`; make up your own element like `<foobarbaz></foobarbaz>` and assign `foobarbaz { display:block; }` to it, to help ensure no unwanted `div` styles get applied.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, making my own element is perfect.

Comment: @Thierry Why is setting the id any different than setting the class. Precedence rules? Also, do you mean that I'd need to check which attributes are set for all divs and override each of them?

Comment: Yes, the id has a higher priority than the class in CSS. You also need to be sure that this ID is unique in the page.But if making a custom element works, that would probably be the best solution to avoir conflicts.